# NHibernate QueryOver with subquery using parent (root) alias = could not resolve property exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
Entity root = null;
var query = Session.QueryOver(() => root);
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Entity>();
subQuery.Where((x) => x.Id == root.Id).Select(Projections.RowCount());
query.WithSubquery.WhereValue(0).Eq(subQuery);
query.List();
```

This doesn't work. I don't get it. I'v seen similar examples that people claim to work. Is it NH 4.04 bug or i'm doind something wrong?

> NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: root of: Entity

Comment: What SQL are you trying to generate?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker select * from foo as t1 where 0!= (select count(*) from foo as t2 where t1.someThing = t2.someThing)

Answer (score 1):

I Figured this out. The exception mentioned, is caught inside NH, and it doesn't break the query. I was debuging code in Visual Studio with enabled "stop on thrown exception" option. And thought I had "only my code" option switched on, for some strange reason exception from NH are shown.

My collegue pointed out that line of code with caught exceptions is highlighted in green, and uncaught are yellow.